# ngIf and hidden are not binding property when i pass the condition from typescript

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular4-forms

I am creating a dynamic form by parsing a json file. So i need to bind the hidden/ngIf based on a condition. I am passing the condition from the typescript file and same thing is using in the html file. Below are my code changes

```
product.component.ts

export class ProductComponent implements OnInit {

  condition : any;
  productForm : FormGroup;

constructor(productFormBuilder : FormBuilder) {
      this.productForm = productFormBuilder.group({
          'name' : ["", [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(5), Validators.maxLength(10)]],
          'test' :["",[]],
          'middleName':["",[]],
          'lastName':["",[]]

      });

      this.condition="!(this.productForm.get('test').value==='testing')";
   }

}

product.component.html

  <form [formGroup]="productForm" (submit)="onSubmit()">
  <div>
      <label>Name</label>
      <input type="text" formControlName="name" name="name" >
      <div *ngIf="productForm.controls['name'].invalid && (productForm.controls['name'].dirty || productForm.controls['name'].touched)">
        <div style="color:red" 
            *ngIf="productForm.controls['name'].errors.required">Name is required</div>
        <div style="color:red" 
            *ngIf="productForm.controls['name'].errors.minlength">Name is minimum of 5 characters</div> 
      </div>

  </div>
  <div>
      <label>Label</label>
      <input type='radio' formControlName='test' value='testing' name='test'> Testing
      <input type='radio' formControlName='test' value='overflow' name='test'> Overflow

  </div>
  <div  [hidden]= "!(this.productForm.get('test').value==='overflow')"> 
    <label>Overflow</label>
    <input type='text' formControlName='middleName' > 

</div>
<div *ngIf="condition">
        <div  >
                <label>Testing</label>
                <input type='text' formControlName='lastName' > 
            </div>
</div>
<div [hidden]="condition">
        <div  >
                <label>Testing</label>
                <input type='text' formControlName='lastName' > 
            </div>
</div>

 <button type="submit">Submit</button>

</form>
```

In my template file i had radio button with name "test", i need to show the respective div based on radio button selection. The binding is working when i place condition directly in the template file and the same thing is not working when i send it from the typescript and using the same in template file. ngIf* showing the right div when on page load but the toggling is not working.

As the form is going to create dynamically by parsing a json, I need to pass the condition from the typescript.

Can someone help me is there anything I am missing.

Comment: `condition` is a non-null string value, which is a truthy value. Your \*ngIf/[hidden] bindings will always be true. Bindings don't accept expressions *as strings*. You can probably generate a function and assign that to `condition` instead, and then invoke it from the template.

Answer (score 1):

First of all `condition` should be boolean type and not string. 
`this.condition="!(this.productForm.get('test').value==='testing')";` should be replaced with 
`this.condition=!(this.productForm.get('test').value==='testing');` 
Secondly, you are missing the change detection in radio selection. Initially, it is set but when you change it, you are not updating the `condition`. 
`<input type='radio' formControlName='test' value='testing' name='test' (click)="updateCondition()"> Testing
 <input type='radio' formControlName='test' value='overflow' name='test' (click)="updateCondition()"> Overflow` 
and then in your component file 
`updateCondition(){
  this.condition=!(this.productForm.get('test').value==='testing');
}`